# Integration of Function Question

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Solve f(x)

$f(x) = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{2\pi x} dx$

my approach:
this can be wrong , suggest me how to approach,thank you for your help

[image]

Comment: you are aware that the expression on the right is a constant

Comment: yes, it is constant and $f(x)=0$ satisfy the equation...

Comment: How it is a constant, I did not get how f(x)=0

Comment: It is because you are integrating a function, $f(x)$ over all $x$ with limits so that is why you have a constant. you may be wanting $$\hat{f}(x) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(s)\mathrm{e}^{-i2\pi s\cdot x}ds$$ ?

Comment: It can be infinity also right, like how I solved it